# What is the word or phrase of the relationship between an account and a bank?

Tags: phrase-requests

I am looking to describe the relationship between a bank account (such as a checking account, a loan, etc.) to a bank or other financial institution.

Right now, I am using *is conducted by*, as in

> Account 123 *is conducted by* My
>   Credit Union.

I have also considered *is held at* (or *is being held at*), and *is managed by*.

But all of these seem awkward. Are there other phrases or words for this relationship that are accurate and more elegant?

Comment: *held at* is the usual phrase and can be understood by all

Comment: you can also say that account was *opened with*, though you'll have to specify that it is still used afterwards.

Comment: @Unreason ... except that accounts currently held by Bank X weren't necessarily opened there, if the bank has subsequently been bought by or merged with another.

Comment: @Dave DuPlantis, yes of course, was not trying to give an answer in the comments, just a suggestion (the account could have been moved, closed, emptied, etc...) so *you have to specify that it is still used afterwards*.

Comment: @Unreason, that still leaves us with the OP's original question, doesn't it? Expressing how it's currently used seems to me to be the issue ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could switch it around:

> The Commonwealth Bank holds account 123

But its normally:

> Account 123 is held at the Commonwealth Bank

Comment: The reason I dislike "is held at" is the the term "account holder" is the person(s) who own the account.

Comment: I have decided on "is held at". Searching Google Books, and then getting context by reading some of the excerpts where the phrases were used really helped. I am naming portions of a computer program, so I was not able to "turn it around".

Answer (score 2):

*Held by* (or *at*) is perhaps the most common phrase in this case. *Managed by* is also quite common. A search turned up several other possible phrases to express this relationship:

Various accounts are also said to be **owned**, **maintained**, **rendered**, **kept**, **controlled**, **administered**, **handled**, **implemented**, **operated**, **run**, and **trusteed** by their various financial institutions.

Comment: I hate to complain, but _owned by_ does not work, as the bank does not own the account.  _Maintained_ seems to refer to an account value. _Rendered_ implies that ownership is transferred. _Controlled_ is performed by the account holder. I could not find [usage examples of account is _administered_, _implemented_, or _trusteed_](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=account+is+implemented%2Caccount+is+administered&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3).  _Handled_, _Operated_ and _run_ refer to way the account is used. On the other hand, _kept_ seems to work OK.

Comment: @Jay: I was just reporting phrases I found using [this](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22account++by++bank%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&ds=bo&sugexp=ldymls&pq=%22account%20%20by%20%20bank%22&xhr=t&q=%22account+*+by+*+bank%22&cp=16&pf=p&sclient=psy&tbo=1&tbm=bks&source=hp&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=%22account+*+by+*+bank%22&pbx=1&fp=9cd650e29bf56da&biw=1280&bih=705) search.

Comment: @Jay: Correction: for some reason my search is not translating in the link in my previous comment. I searched "account * by * bank" in Google Books for the above phrases.

Answer (score 0):

*Serviced* works for me. How about you?

Comment: I did not find any occurrence of the phrase "account is serviced" on the [Google ngram viewer](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=account+is+serviced%2Caccount+is+held&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)