# Word for an account that is managed by an organization

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

*Related, but not equivalent questions:*

- [What is the word or phrase of the relationship between an account and a bank?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29922/what-is-the-word-or-phrase-of-the-relationship-between-an-account-and-a-bank)
- [Word for a computer user without administrative access/privileges](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/403189/word-for-a-computer-user-without-administrative-access-privileges)

### Background

I'm developing a web application. There are several ways in which persons can use our application: they can sign up individually and get a private account, or they can sign up through an organization. Accounts signed up via an organization are 'managed by' that organization (similar to the first link above). These organizational accounts come in two flavours: there are 'basic' accounts and administrator accounts (who can 'do stuff' with the accounts of their organization).

Now, for an account with administrator rights for organization X, we say:

> This account is an **administrator** of organization X.

### Question

I'm looking for a single word to express the relationship between the organization and a non-admin account that is managed by the organization:

> This account is a **[term]** of organization X.

This term would **also** apply to admins, because admin accounts are managed by the organization as well. So admins have two roles with respect to the organization.

### More information

If it helps, we're talking about e-learning software.

- Words we have considered are 'student' and 'learner' (because of our domain). But these don't capture the precise meaning: an account that is 'managed by' the organization is not *necessarily* also *learning* anything (it may only do administrative tasks, for example).
- We're looking for a term like 'learner' and 'administrator' that only captures the property of 'being managed by', without being domain-specific. The meaning should ideally also be transparent to end-users.
- We want this term to have the same grammatical properties as 'administrator' in order to keep our code and the signature of our endpoints consistent. (I can expand on that if necessary.)
- Compound words are acceptable if they sound natural; phrases are not, due to the point above.

Comment: I would call a corporate account a, well, *corporate account.* And I would abstain from mixing accounts and administrators. The account is not the administrator. The administrator is the administrator whose account it is. And especially in corporate context that administrator may well be fifty people, or indeed the entirety of the company.

Comment: We can certainly call them *corporate accounts* in other contexts, but you can't say "This account is a *corporate* of organization X".
For us, 'administratorship' really is linked to the account. The same natural person may have several accounts at several organizations, some of which are administrators of their organization and some of which are not. I.e. a person can have an admin account A at organization X, a 'normal' corporate account B at organization Y and even a private account C not linked to any organization. The first two accounts can be described by the term I'm looking for.

Comment: So to clarify, in that last example, I want to be able to say "A is a [term] of X and B is a [term] of Y. C is not a [term] of any organization. And incidentally, A is also an administrator of X."